# AJAX Toolkit Control Extender problem in Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, toolkit

I have used AJAX toolkit control extender in my site(ASP.net with C#).

When i uploaded my site to the production server it gives the error for ajax toolkit extender.

When i replaced the toolkit script manager with regular script manager the site is working fine but the extended control are not working.

I have contacted to the production server team they are saying we have already provided the facility for ajax toolkit.

How i can solve the problem...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> When i replaced the toolkit script
>   manager with regular script manager
>   the site is working fine but the
>   extended control are not working.

The toolskript manager works like a scriptmanager but adds additional functionality. Using Ajaxcontroltoolkit components without using the toolskriptmanager might break them. (e.g. CollapsablePanelExtender)

- Are you sure you are using the latest stable version of the ajaxcontroltoolkit?
- Have you tried setting up a local IIS to reproduce the problem?
- Are you sure that the AjaxControlToolkit is the problem? Maybe you are using another assembler that is referenced in your GAC but is not deployed to your production server

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about the initial error? Are you saying that it was working locally on the dev machine, and only gives an error on the server? If so, make sure that the AjaxControlToolkit.dll is in the application's bin folder.